# How database sharding based on timestamp and pkid is better in performance?

Tags: sharding, system-design

I was checking a system design of twitter.

**Sharding based on UserID**: We can try storing all the data of a user on one server. While storing, we can pass the UserID to our hash function that will map the user to a database server where we will store all of the user’s tweets, favorites, follows, etc. While querying for tweets/follows/favorites of a user, we can ask our hash function where can we find the data of a user and then read it from there. This approach has a couple of issues:

What if a user becomes hot? There could be a lot of queries on the server holding the user. This high load will affect the performance of our service.
Over time some users can end up storing a lot of tweets or having a lot of follows compared to others. Maintaining a uniform distribution of growing user data is quite difficult.
To recover from these situations either we have to repartition/redistribute our data or use consistent hashing.

**Sharding based on TweetID**: Our hash function will map each TweetID to a random server where we will store that Tweet. To search for tweets, we have to query all servers, and each server will return a set of tweets. A centralized server will aggregate these results to return them to the user. Let’s look into timeline generation example; here are the number of steps our system has to perform to generate a user’s timeline:

Our application (app) server will find all the people the user follows.
App server will send the query to all database servers to find tweets from these people.
Each database server will find the tweets for each user, sort them by recency and return the top tweets.
App server will merge all the results and sort them again to return the top results to the user.
This approach solves the problem of hot users, but, in contrast to sharding by UserID, we have to query all database partitions to find tweets of a user, which can result in higher latencies.

We can further improve our performance by introducing cache to store hot tweets in front of the database servers.

**Sharding based on Tweet creation time**: Storing tweets based on creation time will give us the advantage of fetching all the top tweets quickly and we only have to query a very small set of servers. The problem here is that the traffic load will not be distributed.

**What if we can combine sharding by TweetID and Tweet creation time?** If we don’t store tweet creation time separately and use TweetID to reflect that, we can get benefits of both the approaches. This way it will be quite quick to find the latest Tweets. For this, we must make each TweetID universally unique in our system and each TweetID should contain a timestamp too.

We can use epoch time for this. Let’s say our TweetID will have two parts: the first part will be representing epoch seconds and the second part will be an auto-incrementing sequence. So, to make a new TweetID, we can take the current epoch time and append an auto-incrementing number to it. We can figure out the shard number from this TweetID and store it there. **How does this approach helps better than the above approaches?**